# Surface Difference TIN Output in ArcGIS | Python Code

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, 3d-analyst, tin, error-000732

Why does the output TIN option does not work when executing it through a python script or a model builder simulation run? As you will see in the messages below, the surface difference successfully runs but never creates the TIN output file. However, the output shapefile is created. Maybe there is a bug in ArcGIS 10.2 in relation to this tool??

I have one script that has various tools, here is the part that i am having significant difficulty:

```
#Trigger Surface Difference to yield ppp elevation, Insert optional directories for TIN output
    in_surface = tin4
    in_reference = "C:\\Standalone\\ppp"
    out_tin_basename = "C:\\Standalone\\tin0041214_ppp"
    out_tin_folder = env.workspace
    out_feature_class = "C:\\Standalone\\0041214_ppp.shp"
    Output_Raster = ""
    arcpy.SurfaceDifference_3d(in_surface,in_reference,out_feature_class, out_tin_folder = out_tin_folder, out_tin_basename = out_tin_basename)
    print "Surface Difference generated"

    #Generate Surface Contours off the PPP Survey surface
    arcpy.SurfaceContour_3d( out_tin_basename ,"C:\\Standalone\\0041214_contours.shp",1,"","Contour","","","Index_Cont",1)  #Check for contour field add
    print "Contours generated"
```

**This is the error messages that i am catching:**

```
The program has began processing 2015-03-19 12:46:19.639000
Feature Class Created
Coordinates Added
TIN created
TIN delineated
Surface Difference generated
Executing: SurfaceContour C:\Standalone\tin0041214_ppp C:/Standalone\0041214_contours.shp 1 0 Contour 0 # Index_Cont 1 0
Start Time: Thu Mar 19 12:52:40 2015
Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000732: Input Surface: Dataset C:\Standalone\tin0041214_ppp does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (SurfaceContour).
Failed at Thu Mar 19 12:52:40 2015 (Elapsed Time: 0.00 seconds)
Duration: 0:06:21.170000
```

Answer (score 1):

After further tweaking, I was able to solve the issue. I had to shorten the TIN's output file name. It appears that the length of the filename can't be longer than a certain amount of characters.

`out_tin_basename = "t0041214_ppp"`  was the new output tin filename.